# Why do statisticians need to know sampling technique

Tags: sampling

Many statistical courses teach sampling techniques, such as rejection sampling and importance sampling, to sample data from a distribution. What are some concrete scenarios where a statistician needs to apply a sampling technique?

Comment: Probably the most common application of simulation these days is Bayesian statistics, where we approximate the posterior distribution by a sample from it.

Answer (score 3):

One reasonable perspective on statistics / econometrics is that the estimated model should be able to reproduce the data actually observed ([Rubin 1984](https://projecteuclid.org/journalArticle/Download?urlId=10.1214%2Faos%2F1176346785); [McFadden, 1989](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1913621); [Gouriéroux et al., 1993](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2285076); [Gelman et al., 2014](https://amzn.to/3gcl47m)). In order to do so, sampling from the potential (statistical) model via pseudo-random generators is paramount.

As commented by [John Madden](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/82893/john-madden), [Bayesian statistics](https://amzn.to/3EOUGe5) is strongly connected with sampling / simulation, since this is often the only feasible way to represent the posterior distribution.